# Laravel : To rename an uploaded file automatically

Tags: laravel

I am allowing users to upload any kind of file on my page, but there might be a clash in names of files. So, I want to rename the file automatically, so that anytime any file gets uploaded, **in the database and in the folder after upload**, the name of the file gets changed also when other user downloads the same file, renamed file will get downloaded.
I tried:

```
if (Input::hasFile('file')){
        echo "Uploaded</br>";
        $file = Input::file('file');
        
        $file ->move('uploads');
        $fileName = Input::get('rename_to');
        
    }
```

But, the name gets changed to something like:

> php5DEB.php
>
> phpCFEC.php

**What can I do to maintain the file in the same type and format and just change its name?**

**I also want to know how can I show the recently uploaded file on the page and make other users download it??**

Comment: Though allowing users to rename the file is a good option, however it is recommended to add some unique identifier to the file name. Lets say your file name is `image.png` add the current time stamp and it will become `image_timestamp.png`. If a user again upload file with `image.png` since the time stamp will be different and hence if you follow above method you won't get clash between file names.

Comment: Use laravel storage instead to handle file upload as I mentioned in the answer

Comment: I modified my answer as mentioned below after @cpburnz's input. Please find it useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For unique file Name saving

In 5.3 (best for me because use md5_file hashname in Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile):

```
public function saveFile(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('your_input_name')->store('your_path','your_disk');
}
```

In 5.4 (use not unique Str::random(40) hashname in Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile). I Use this code to ensure unique name:

```
public function saveFile(Request $request) {
    $md5Name = md5_file($request->file('your_input_name')->getRealPath());
    $guessExtension = $request->file('your_input_name')->guessExtension();
    $file = $request->file('your_input_name')->storeAs('your_path', $md5Name.'.'.$guessExtension  ,'your_disk');
}
```

Comment: this rename is during save action. In my case, I POST my file to a web-service so I don't use `store`. I would like to rename php  hash to original filename but it seems not possible

Answer (score 13):

Use this one

```
$file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

Comment: This way worked for Laravel FTP filesystem too!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use php core function `rename(oldname,newName)`   http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

Find this tutorial helpful.
[file uploads 101](https://laracasts.com/lessons/file-uploads-101)

Everything you need to know about file upload is there.

-- Edit --

I modified my answer as below after valuable input from @cpburnz and @Moinuddin Quadri. Thanks guys.

First your storage driver should look like this in `/your-app/config/filesystems.php`

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public'), // hence /your-app/storage/app/public
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

You can use other file drivers like `s3` but for my example I'm working on `local` driver.

In your `Controller` you do the following.

```
$file = request()->file('file'); // Get the file from request
$yourModel->create([
    'file' => $file->store('my_files', 'public'),
]);
```

Your file get uploaded to `/your-app/storage/app/public/my_files/` and you can access the uploaded file like

```
asset('storage/'.$yourModel->image)
```

Make sure you do

```
php artisan storage:link
```

to generate a [simlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) in your `/your-app/public/` that points to `/your-app/storage/app/public` so you could access your files publicly. [More info on filesystem - the public disk.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#the-public-disk)

By this approach you could persists the same file name as that is uploaded. And the great thing is `Laravel` generates an unique name for the file so there could be no duplicates.

To answer the second part of your question that is to show recently uploaded files, as you persist a reference for the file in the database, you could access them by your database record and make it `->orderBy('id', 'DESC');`. You could use whatever your logic is and order by descending order.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

You can rename your uploaded file as you want . you can use either move or storeAs method with appropiate param.

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$file = $request->file('product_image');
foreach($file as $singleFile){
    $original_name = strtolower(trim($singleFile->getClientOriginalName()));
    $file_name = time().rand(100,999).$original_name;
     // use one of following 
    // $singleFile->move($destinationPath,$file_name); public folder
    // $singleFile->storeAs('product',$file_name);  storage folder
    $fileArray[] = $file_name;
}
print_r($fileArray);
```

Answer (score -2):

correct usage.

```
$fileName = Input::get('rename_to');
Input::file('photo')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
```

Comment: It is showing error : FatalErrorException in UploadController.php line 19:
Call to a member function move() on null

Answer (score -2):

at the top after namespace
use Storage;

```
    Just do something like this ....
```

// read files 
    $excel = $request->file('file');

```
// rename file
$excelName = time().$excel->getClientOriginalName();

// rename to anything
$excelName = substr($excelName, strpos($excelName, '.c'));
$excelName = 'Catss_NSE_'.date("M_D_Y_h:i_a_").$excelName;
$excel->move(public_path('equities'),$excelName);
```

This guy collect the extension only:

```
 $excelName = substr($excelName, strpos($excelName, '.c'));
```

This guy rename its: 
$excelName = 'Catss_NSE_'.date("M_D_Y_h:i_a_").$excelName;