# Laravel Form with Image uploading in laravel5.3

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have an form which contain complete data including image but first I want to upload image and get the image file path and then store all the data into database in LARAVEL What should I do and how?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588306/laravel-to-rename-an-uploaded-file-automatically/41592339#41592339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to install image intervention

```
composer require intervention/image
```

then you will need to setup your form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/index/send/here" method="POST" >
<!--Notice the enctype -->
</form>
```

I made this function in my helpers file so I could upload images with one line of code. Here is that helper function.

```
function upload_image($path, $prefix, $storage_path, $width, $height){
  $extention = $path->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $filename = $prefix.'_' . date("jFYhis") . '.' . $extention;
  Image::make($path)->fit($width,$height)->save(public_path($storage_path . $filename));
  return $storage_path.$filename;
}
```

then in my controller all I have to do is this.

```
public function controllerFunction(Request $request){
    upload_image($request->file('nameOfFormField'), 'prefix', '/directoryInPublicFolder', 300,300);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it helps.

Answer (score 1):

So Simple checkout below links

1. http://clivern.com/how-to-create-file-upload-with-laravel/
2. http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-53-image-upload-with-validation-exampleexample.html

it is perfectly understand and easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks for the link